# WebSecurity vs FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I guess I am trying to mix two providers in project but I am looking to use websecurity in conjunction to my forms authentication. I need websecurity for OAUTH authentication using Facebook, and google.

The error that I am getting when I try to login using facebook is

To call this method, the `Membership.Provider` property must be an instance of `ExtendedMembershipProvider`.

Here are the code samples. How can I use both?

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }
```

and

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Could possibly be related to the same issue as me [MVC4 ExtendedMembershipProvider and entityframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181186/)
.. I removed the universal providers nuget package and this particular error dissappeared.

Also this ["very recent"](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) article by Jon Galloway may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you might want to save yourself all this effort.  The MVC 4 Internet template comes with four external identity providers out of the box.  I have tested them and Google Accounts, Microsoft account, Facebook login, and Twitter login all work fine, with zero lines of code!

I think the same is provided with the Web Form template too.

More info at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of `ExtendedMembershipProvider`. For ex: the built-in `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

Every `ExtendedMembershipProvider` **IS A** `MembershipProvider` .

Read more at [Jon Galloway's Blog.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)